# Update and correct a table which has a composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

I have a table in a database that is used to record items of equipment at a particular premise.  It has a composite primary key made up of the id (in the form of an int) of the premise's id and then a separate number (in this case a decimal) that gets added for each individual piece of equipment.

Whilst this setup tends to work well at first producing a contiguous set of numbers for the second part of the composite key after a few years as bits of equipment are added or removed from the schedule it starts to look like the example below.

[image: Composite key after a few years]

My question is really twofold.  Firstly is there a query that could be written against the second part of the composite key that would restore a contiguous set of numbers to it? For example simply replacing 38.3 with 39 would immediately produce a conflict with the existing record with the number 39.  I'm assuming that the way to approach this is probably via some sort of count and then working backwards through the table, though I suspect that even doing it that way could result in conflicts that would cause the update to fail.

Secondly and perhaps more importantly this was designed many many years ago.  I'm sure that there are better ways to structure such a table so I'd welcome some 'best practice' ideas for this type of scenario.

Comment: The order of items for an equipment seems very important for you. Why is this so? (Sorry I am asking, but usually the order of parts doesn't matter. A chair consists of legs, seat and back; why would I have to mention them in a particular order?)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  Personally it's of no interest to me at all, but there are reports that get produced from this table.  So imagine a building that contains hundreds of items, the list acts both as an inventory and also a plan to allows engineers to walk round and service them, being able to tidy the list up makes sense when viewed with that that in mind.

Comment: Hm, still, why the order? If I want to cluster the items, e.g. per room, I'd have another column `room`, so I can both print an alphabetical list as well as a list per room. What I am saying is: I can usually order entries by their attributes. There are exceptions such as positions in an invoice, but these are usually write-once things. (I will never have to insert an invoice position between two existing ones.) So the question is: do you have all attributes to apply different orders to?

Comment: If you really need a position where you must insert positions inbetween later, then have a column for the position. That doesn't have to be the primary key though. Have a part number per equipment as key and a position as an attribute. Keys should never change. Attributes can.

Comment: These tables stem from old paper based lists circa thirty years ago.  They were used to allow engineers to find their own way around large complex sites where over the years things would change.  When I first started to try and automate the process the table design was what I came up with.  Yes I know it's far from ideal and that is why I'm trying to change things.  First stage is to get a new contiguous number for the second part of the id, then I can work on designing new tables that work more in the way of your last comment.  The original mistake was of my own making, now I'd like to fix it

Comment: You can easily create a new column `position` and fill it via `row_number() over (partition by equipment_id order by item_id)`. Later whenever you have to insert a new position you'd update, say, `update mytable set position = position + 1 where position >= @new_position`.

Comment: That sounds like a good compromise.  Thanks

Comment: Proposed an answer. Adapted results.

Comment: @DomSinclair It would be nice of you, if you would also mark the correct answer as accepted. It will give points to both of us, then.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id_1 int NOT NULL, id_2 decimal NOT NULL, data text NOT NULL);
```

**ROW_NUMBER**

You can generate an ordered `id_2` int by using `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
SELECT id_1,  
       id_2,  
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_1 ORDER BY id_2),  
       data  
FROM foo;
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function will begin numbering each set of rows having the same `id_1` (`PARTITION BY`) in ascending order of `id_2` (`ORDER BY`).
You wrote that `(id_1, id_2)` is a key, so it's unique. Then you don't need a tie breaker. If you would need a tie breaker, because `(id_1, id_2)` were not unique, then you could just add another column to your `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause.

Example result (without data):

```
id_1 | id_2 | ROW_NUMBER  
------------------------  
   1 |  1.1 |          1  
   1 |  1.2 |          2  
   1 |  2.1 |          3  
   1 |  5.5 |          4  
   2 |    1 |          1  
   2 |  3.3 |          2
```

So here both `(id_1, id_2)` and `(id_1, ROW_NUMBER)` are unique keys identifying the rows.

**Multiply decimal fractions away**

Assume that decimal numbers only have 1 decimal behind the point.
Then you can just multiply them all by 10 and cast them to int.
This way, you will retain a close relationship between this data and how it was before, which may be good for historic reasons.

```
id_1 | id_2 | id_2 * 10 :: int  
------------------------  
   1 |  1.1 |         11  
   1 |  1.2 |         12  
   1 |  2.1 |         21  
   1 |  5.5 |         55  
   2 |    1 |         10  
   2 |  3.3 |         33
```

You can keep both the multiplied column as part of a new key and the old `id_2 decimal` column as unrelated data only column.

** Splitting the `id_2` into two columns **

This is a variation of the **ROW_NUMBER** approach by rounding `id_2` down (floor) and using the `ROW_NUMBER` as third column for unique key `(id_1, floor(id_2), ROW_NUMBER)`.

```
SELECT id_1,  
       id_2,  -- keep, if needed
       floor(id_2) AS "id_2_floor",
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_1 ORDER BY id_2) AS "id_3",  
       data  
FROM foo;  

id_1 | id_2 | id_2_floor | id_3 (ROW_NUMBER)  
--------------------------------------------  
   1 |  1.1 |          1 | 1  
   1 |  1.2 |          1 | 2
   1 |  2.1 |          2 | 1
   1 |  5.5 |          5 | 1
   2 |    1 |          1 | 1
   2 |  3.3 |          3 | 1
```

This will mix up the fractional parts of your decimal numbers though.

**Splitting decimal into two ints at the decimal point**

This approach splits a decimal number (1.2) into two ints (1, 2).
You can then make `(id_1, floor( id_2 ), id_2 * 10 % 10)` unique key.

```
SELECT id_1,  
       id_2,  -- keep if needed  
       floor( id_2 ) AS "id_2_new",  
       int( id_2 * 10 % 10 ) AS "id_3",  -- and cast to int
       data  
FROM foo;  

id_1 | id_2 | id_2_new | id_3  
-----------------------------  
   1 |  1.1 |        1 | 1  
   1 |  1.2 |        1 | 2  
   1 |  2.1 |        2 | 1  
   1 |  5.5 |        5 | 5  
   2 |    1 |        1 | 0  
   2 |  3.3 |        3 | 3
```

This approach will allow you to reconstruct the original `id_2` column values at any time using

```
SELECT id_1,  
       double( id_2 + id_3 / 10 ) AS "id_2_old"  
FROM   foo;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I have just tried this with a dummy database that I created very quickly.  There is no doubt that your original query works, in that it produces an ordered list (subject to the very real caveat that one only uses one decimal place.  It gets a little more unwieldy once you have two or three.  I freely accept that the mess is of my own making born of a time when I knew much less.

Comment: I found 4 different approaches. I hope one fits what you want. Maybe you can go with the 4th approach **Splitting decimal into two ints at the decimal point**. Also, we are all here to learn :) It's fine if I make mistakes, as long as i learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Indeed.  I am in the process of creating new tables in the test db to more closely resemble what I have and then work with the third and fourth approaches.  I have marked up your answer in the meantime.  thank you.

Comment: If you also accept the answer because it's correct and helpful, then we both get points. Or come back later, to get your points for marking correct answers, if you wish :).
In my opinion, the fundamental problem with these decimals is, that they contain two different parts of information in just one column. Decimals for an account balance is fine. Decimals as part of a department + room identification is not. You can also keep the old `id_2` column as text for historic reasons. For DB normalization, consider [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for starters.